# telebot pyton. Мне нужно чтобы только при в вводе ключа в переменной key начинал работать бот. Помогите осуществить

Tags: python, telebot, key

Мне нужно чтобы только при вводе ключа находящийся в переменной key начинал работать код. Помогите пожалуйста выполнить данную задачу.
Код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from telebot import types
import time
from urllib.request import urlopen
Key=120301021012234125
bot = telebot.TeleBot('http api')
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])

def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Руссикй язык")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('История')
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Обществознание")
    btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Геометрия')
    btn5 = types.KeyboardButton("Алгебра",)
    btn6 = types.KeyboardButton('Физика')
    btn7 = types.KeyboardButton("Литература")
    btn8 = types.KeyboardButton('География')
    markup.add(btn1, btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Выберите предмет", reply_markup=markup)
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Алгебра')
def get_user_photo(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://i.imgur.com/ofwPfHE.png")
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Руссикй язык')
def get_user_photo(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://i.imgur.com/ofwPfHE.png")
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Литература')
def get_user_photo(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://i.imgur.com/ofwPfHE.png")
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Обществознание')
def get_user_photo(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://i.imgur.com/ofwPfHE.png")
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Геометрия')
def get_user_photo(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://i.imgur.com/ofwPfHE.png")
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Физика')
def get_user_photo(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://i.imgur.com/ofwPfHE.png")
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Вы имеет ввиду, что администратор хост-сервера должен ввести код активации, чтобы запустить бота, или что пользователь должен переслать код активации в сообщении, чтобы начать взаимодействие с ботом?

Answer (score 0):

Вот возможное решение проблемы:

```
KEY = "123456"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(KEY)
```

С большой буквы создаёте константу и прописываете в ней ключ а после передаёте константу в аргументы функции